# Using autopep8 on a very long line: strange output and very slow

Tags: python

I am trying out the `autopep8` tool. It has worked well for all my test cases except for one. In that case I have a function that calculates the volume of a hexahedron:

```
def getHexVolume3(x,y,z):
    v=-x[0]*y[3]*z[4]+x[0]*y[4]*z[3]-x[1]*y[3]*z[0]+x[1]*y[0]*z[3]+x[1]*y[4]*z[0]-x[1]*y[0]*z[4]-y[0]*z[3]*x[4]+y[0]*x[3]*z[4]-y[1]*z[3]*x[0]+y[1]*x[0]*z[4]+y[1]*x[3]*z[0]-z[0]*x[3]*y[4]+z[0]*y[3]*x[4]-z[1]*x[3]*y[0]+z[1]*y[0]*x[4]+z[1]*y[3]*x[0]-x[1]*y[2]*z[0]+x[1]*y[2]*z[5]+x[1]*y[0]*z[2]+x[1]*y[5]*z[0]-x[1]*y[5]*z[2]-x[1]*y[0]*z[5]-y[1]*z[0]*x[5]-y[1]*z[2]*x[0]+y[1]*z[2]*x[5]+y[1]*x[0]*z[5]+y[1]*x[2]*z[0]-y[1]*x[2]*z[5]-z[1]*x[0]*y[5]-z[1]*x[2]*y[0]+z[1]*x[2]*y[5]+z[1]*y[0]*x[5]+z[1]*y[2]*x[0]-z[1]*y[2]*x[5]-y[1]*z[0]*x[4]-z[1]*x[0]*y[4]-x[0]*y[3]*z[7]+x[0]*y[7]*z[3]+x[2]*y[3]*z[7]-x[2]*y[7]*z[3]-x[2]*y[3]*z[0]+x[2]*y[0]*z[3]-y[0]*z[3]*x[7]+y[0]*x[3]*z[7]-y[2]*z[3]*x[0]+y[2]*x[3]*z[0]+y[2]*z[3]*x[7]-y[2]*x[3]*z[7]+z[2]*x[3]*y[7]-z[0]*x[3]*y[7]+z[0]*y[3]*x[7]-z[2]*y[3]*x[7]-z[2]*x[3]*y[0]+z[2]*y[3]*x[0]-x[1]*y[6]*z[2]+x[1]*y[2]*z[6]-x[2]*y[6]*z[3]+x[2]*y[3]*z[6]-x[2]*y[3]*z[1]+x[2]*y[1]*z[3]-z[1]*y[2]*x[6]-z[2]*x[3]*y[1]+z[2]*y[3]*x[1]+z[2]*x[3]*y[6]-z[2]*y[3]*x[6]+y[2]*z[3]*x[6]-y[2]*z[3]*x[1]+y[2]*x[3]*z[1]-y[2]*x[3]*z[6]+z[1]*x[2]*y[6]+y[1]*z[2]*x[6]-y[1]*x[2]*z[6]-x[0]*y[7]*z[4]+x[0]*y[4]*z[7]+x[5]*y[7]*z[4]-x[5]*y[4]*z[7]-x[5]*y[0]*z[4]+x[1]*y[6]*z[5]-x[1]*y[5]*z[6]+z[1]*x[6]*y[5]-z[1]*y[6]*x[5]-z[5]*x[1]*y[4]+z[5]*y[1]*x[4]+z[5]*x[6]*y[4]-z[5]*y[6]*x[4]-y[5]*z[1]*x[4]+y[5]*z[6]*x[4]+y[5]*x[1]*z[4]-y[5]*x[6]*z[4]-x[5]*y[1]*z[4]+x[5]*y[4]*z[1]+y[1]*z[6]*x[5]-y[1]*x[6]*z[5]-x[6]*y[2]*z[5]+x[6]*y[5]*z[2]-x[6]*y[7]*z[2]-x[6]*y[5]*z[7]+x[6]*y[2]*z[7]+x[6]*y[7]*z[5]-x[2]*y[5]*z[6]+x[7]*y[3]*z[4]-x[7]*y[4]*z[3]+y[6]*z[3]*x[7]+y[6]*z[7]*x[4]-y[6]*x[3]*z[7]-y[6]*x[7]*z[4]-x[3]*y[7]*z[4]+x[3]*y[4]*z[7]-x[4]*y[3]*z[7]+x[4]*y[7]*z[3]+x[6]*y[3]*z[7]+x[6]*y[7]*z[4]-x[6]*y[4]*z[7]-x[6]*y[7]*z[3]+z[6]*x[3]*y[7]+z[6]*x[7]*y[4]-z[6]*y[3]*x[7]-z[6]*y[7]*x[4]+x[2]*y[6]*z[5]+z[6]*x[2]*y[7]+z[6]*x[7]*y[5]-z[6]*y[2]*x[7]-z[6]*y[7]*x[5]-x[5]*y[6]*z[2]+x[5]*y[2]*z[6]+y[6]*z[2]*x[7]+y[6]*z[7]*x[5]-y[6]*x[2]*z[7]-y[6]*x[7]*z[5]+x[5]*y[4]*z[0]-y[0]*z[7]*x[4]+y[0]*x[7]*z[4]-y[5]*z[0]*x[4]+y[5]*x[0]*z[4]+y[5]*z[7]*x[4]-y[5]*x[7]*z[4]-z[0]*x[7]*y[4]+z[0]*y[7]*x[4]+z[5]*x[7]*y[4]-z[5]*y[7]*x[4]-z[5]*x[0]*y[4]+z[5]*y[0]*x[4]+x[5]*y[6]*z[4]-x[5]*y[4]*z[6]

    v=v/12
    return v
```

Running `autopep8` on this function:

```
$ autopep8 t.py
```

takes 2 minutes and 10 seconds to complete and gives output:

```
def getHexVolume3(x, y, z):
    v = -x[0] * y[3] * z[4] + x[0] * y[4] * z[3] - x[1] * y[3] * z[0] + x[1] * y[0] * z[3] + x[1] * y[4] * z[0] - x[1] * y[0] * z[4] - y[0] * z[3] * x[4] + y[0] * x[3] * z[4] - y[1] * z[3] * x[0] + y[1] * x[0] * z[4] + y[1] * x[3] * z[0] - z[0] * x[3] * y[4] + z[0] * y[3] * x[4] - z[1] * x[3] * y[0] + z[1] * y[0] * x[4] + z[1] * y[3] * x[0] - x[1] * y[2] * z[0] + x[1] * y[2] * z[5] + x[1] * y[0] * z[2] + x[1] * y[5] * z[0] - x[1] * y[5] * z[2] - x[1] * y[0] * z[5] - y[1] * z[0] * x[5] - y[1] * z[2] * x[0] + y[1] * z[2] * x[5] + y[1] * x[0] * z[5] + y[1] * x[2] * z[0] - y[1] * x[2] * z[5] - z[1] * x[0] * y[5] - z[1] * x[2] * y[0] + z[1] * x[2] * y[5] + z[1] * y[0] * x[5] + z[1] * y[2] * x[0] - z[1] * y[2] * x[5] - y[1] * z[0] * x[4] - z[1] * x[0] * y[4] - x[0] * y[3] * z[7] + x[0] * y[7] * z[3] + x[2] * y[3] * z[7] - x[2] * y[7] * z[3] - x[2] * y[3] * z[0] + x[2] * y[0] * z[3] - y[0] * z[3] * x[7] + y[0] * x[3] * z[7] - y[2] * z[3] * x[0] + y[2] * x[3] * z[0] + y[2] * z[3] * x[7] - y[2] * x[3] * z[7] + z[2] * x[3] * y[7] - z[0] * x[3] * y[7] + z[0] * y[3] * x[7] - z[2] * y[3] * x[7] - z[2] * x[3] * y[0] + z[2] * y[3] * x[0] - x[1] * y[6] * z[2] + x[1] * y[2] * z[6] - x[2] * y[6] * z[3] + x[2] * y[3] * z[6] - x[2] * y[3] * z[1] + x[2] * y[1] * z[3] - z[1] * y[2] * x[6] - z[2] * x[3] * y[1] + z[2] * y[3] * x[1] + z[2] * x[3] * y[6] - z[2] * y[3] * x[6] + y[2] * z[3] * x[6] - y[2] * z[3] * x[1] + y[2] * x[3] * z[1] - y[2] * x[3] * z[6] + z[1] * x[2] * y[6] + y[1] * z[2] * x[6] - y[1] * x[2] * \
        z[6] - x[0] * y[7] * z[4] + x[0] * y[4] * z[7] + x[5] * y[7] * z[4] - x[5] * y[4] * z[7] - x[5] * y[0] * z[4] + x[1] * y[6] * z[5] - x[1] * y[5] * z[6] + z[1] * x[6] * y[5] - z[1] * y[6] * x[5] - z[5] * x[1] * y[4] + z[5] * y[1] * x[4] + z[5] * x[6] * y[4] - z[5] * y[6] * x[4] - y[5] * z[1] * x[4] + y[5] * z[6] * x[4] + y[5] * x[1] * z[4] - y[5] * x[6] * z[4] - x[5] * y[1] * z[4] + x[5] * y[4] * z[1] + y[1] * z[6] * x[5] - y[1] * x[6] * z[5] - x[6] * y[2] * z[5] + x[6] * y[5] * z[2] - x[6] * y[7] * z[2] - x[6] * y[5] * z[7] + x[6] * y[2] * z[7] + x[6] * y[7] * z[5] - x[2] * y[5] * z[6] + x[7] * y[3] * z[4] - x[7] * y[4] * z[3] + y[6] * z[3] * x[7] + y[6] * z[7] * x[4] - y[6] * x[3] * z[7] - y[6] * x[7] * z[4] - x[3] * y[7] * z[4] + x[3] * y[4] * \
        z[7] - x[4] * y[3] * z[7] + x[4] * y[7] * z[3] + x[6] * y[3] * z[7] + x[6] * y[7] * z[4] - x[6] * y[4] * z[7] - x[6] * y[7] * z[3] + z[6] * x[3] * y[7] + z[6] * x[7] * y[4] - z[6] * y[3] * x[7] - z[6] * y[7] * x[4] + x[2] * y[6] * z[5] + z[6] * x[2] * y[7] + z[6] * x[7] * y[5] - z[6] * y[2] * x[7] - z[6] * y[7] * x[5] - x[5] * y[6] * z[2] + x[5] * y[2] * z[6] + y[6] * z[2] * \
        x[7] + y[6] * z[7] * x[5] - y[6] * x[2] * z[7] - y[6] * x[7] * z[5] + x[5] * y[4] * z[0] - y[0] * z[7] * x[4] + y[0] * x[7] * z[4] - y[5] * z[0] * x[4] + y[5] * x[0] * z[4] + y[5] * z[7] * \
        x[4] - y[5] * x[7] * z[4] - z[0] * x[7] * y[4] + z[0] * y[7] * x[4] + z[5] * x[7] * y[4] - z[5] * \
        y[7] * x[4] - z[5] * x[0] * y[4] + z[5] * y[0] * \
        x[4] + x[5] * y[6] * z[4] - x[5] * y[4] * z[6]
    v = v / 12
    return v
```

How can the run time and the output from `autopep8` be improved for this case?

Comment: Offtopic: Yikes, what a function :O

Comment: It seems like the program takes very long and produces incorrect output (it doesn't look very PEP8-ish to me) ... This sound like a problem in the program to me. [Reporting a bug](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8/issues) may be more appropriate.

Comment: I would restructure that code to work over a list of tuples e.g. `v = sum((n * x[i] * y[j] * z[k]) for n, i, j, k in [(-1, 0, 3, 4), (1, 0, 4, 3), ...])`